# Why should I create a MySql table containing index only?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, relational-database

I'm following a Java Spring tutorial to learn some basic information about the secure login in a web app.
In this tutorial, the author has created 3 MySql table to manage the authentication:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  KEY `user` (`user_id`),
  KEY `role` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table "roles" contains the user role (for example "Admin", "User" etc...).
The table "users" contains the user login and password.

So, I can't understand why the table "user_roles" has been created! The relation between "roles" and "users" is one-to-one, so I could insert an index for these 2 tables and delete the "user_roles"...is it right?
Why should I need to join the tables "users --> user_roles --> roles" instead of "users --> roles" ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: users --> roles works only for a on to many relation ship. The other case is for many to many relationship

Comment: @Jens thanks! So, if I would create a one to one relationship, should i integrate the column "role" in the users table? In this case, the tables roles and user_roles are not useful anymore...

Comment: If most alluser has a role, you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1:1 relationship, have just one table. (There are exceptions, but I don't see any reason for such here.)

If you have many `users` in each `role` but a `user` is in only one `role`, then add `role_id` to the `Users` table.  This is 1:many.  You may need `INDEX(role_id)`.

If a `user` can have many `roles` and each `role` can have many `users`, then you need many:many.  And this would be the optimal way to write the 3rd table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, role_id),
  KEY         (`role_id`, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

In some sense, that is an index-only table, since the `PRIMARY KEY` contains all the fields.

The `(6)` in `INT(6)` is meaningless.  In particular, it does not give you 6-digit integers, it still gives you 4-byte signed integers up to 2 billion.  Perhaps you should use `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` for values of 0..16M.  Or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for 2-byte values of 0..64K.

Comment: Wow! Thanks man!! It's more clear now! :) anyway, the relationship is 1:many, so i choose your first option! ;)